# key conflict by using unpacking kwargs in format method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to print a string by format method with unpack kwargs. however for gender input that need to be mapping with one dictionary. the only way I can find is to create a dictionary and use different key. but it does not seems like a good way to do it. any though?

```
def func(**kwargs):
    _m = {'h': 'he', 's': 'she'}
    print('This is {name}. {gender} is a {position}'.format(gender=_m[kwargs['sex']], **kwargs))


#correct
func(name='Jon', sex='h', position='Engineer')
#correct
func(name='Jon', sex='s', position='Engineer')
#incorrect
func(name='Jon', gender='s', position='Engineer')
```

Comment: Don't know if I understand, the function can receive sex or gender as argument? Both should be treated the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll get `KeyError` if you use your code in the last example as you're not passing a `sex` argument which you're attempting to retrieve from your internal `_m` dict.

There is nothing wrong with just updating the `kwargs` dict with whatever local data you want and using only the `gender` attribute, e.g.:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    _m = {'h': 'he', 's': 'she'}
    kwargs["gender"] = _m[kwargs["gender"]]
    print('This is {name}. {gender} is a {position}'.format(**kwargs))
```

You can also update multiple fields by creating a dict mapping:

```
def func(**kwargs):
    replacements = {"gender": {"h": "he", "s": "she"}}
    for field in replacements:
        kwargs[field] = replacements[field].get(kwargs.get(field, None), None)
    print('This is {name}. {gender} is a {position}'.format(**kwargs))
```

And then you can populate the `replacements` dict with as many fields as you want to do pre-processing replacement based on the passed arguments.

You can even declare default values if they are not passed, for example if your `replacements` dict is set as:

```
replacements = {"gender": {"h": "he", "s": "she", None: "it"}}
```

Call with a missing `gender` attribute will result in:

```
func(name='Robot', position='Engineer')
# This is Robot. it is a Engineer
```